# problems with online repository

Tags: eclipse, svn, projectlocker

I'm doing a project with omnet++ (which is based on Eclipse) and I wanted to create an online repository on projectlocker.com for it, so I typed:

```
svn import /home/paul/myProject   https://pl3.projectlocker.com/myaccount/myrepository --username=myUsername
```

Now, by just going into my project folder, how can I store all the possible changes that I've made into my online repository?

```
svn commit
```

won't do it.   I've also downloaded subclipse 1.0, but it doesn't seem to be all that helpful on this matter.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: What is not working with svn commit? Do you get an error? What does `svn status` return?

Comment: svn commit returns:
svn: Commit failed (details follow): svn: Directory '/home/paul/myproject/examples/wireless/voiceoverwifiRWMA/results/.svn' containing working copy admin area is missing.    svn status returns the list of all the files in my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

svn export is not the right command to use in this case, you need to use svn checkout.

Comment: Well, I used import, not export.  Ok, so I guess the first thing I had to do was to this svn checkout, and only after that start making any changes to my code. Is that right or am I missing something?

Comment: oops, yeah you need to use a svn checkout after import.